# Can RabbitMQ client APIs for AMQP be used for connecting to Kafka?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

I am building a Kafka Connector for AMQP. Just wanted to know whether RabbitMQ client APIs for AMQP be used to build Kafka Connector for AMQP messages.

Comment: So, you want to use the RabbitMQ AMQP client with Kafka, right ?

Comment: Yes.And, I assume it is possible.

Comment: Kafka does not support `AMQP`. Why don't use the kafka client directly ?

Comment: We are building a connector for the same purpose.